# How can I enable to copy (to clipboard) from Select2 and paste it in another instance?

Tags: jquery, clipboard, jquery-select2, copy-paste, jquery-select2-4

I would like to enable a user to copy and paste selections between Select2 selection elements.

Pasting should work by setting tokenSeparators. But I do not manage to copy something form a select element. (Because I can not select the current selection, Ctrl-C copies nothing and the context menu does not allow copying.)

Is there any possibility like a Select2 option I did not see or do I have to handle this by programming? (I could bind to the copy event and probably write the clipboard data there. No yet sure if this works on several browsers.)

Basic code so far:

```
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

js script code:

```
$("select").select2({
  tokenSeparators: [' ']
})
```

---

extended on 22.3.16:

By setting -user-select as suggested by kevin-brown the options become selectable. But at least in chrome only when selecting all options by mouse from left to right. Still potential for improvement.

```
.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple {
    -webkit-user-select: all;
    -moz-user-select: all;
    -ms-user-select: all;
}
```

(taken from [user select in mozilla developper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select))

try it [in this fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/og0h7p5u/3/) (snippet did not work)

Comment: This isn't built into Select2 at all, and I have a feeling you might be able to do it by dropping the `user-select` CSS around selections.

Comment: setting `-xxx-user-select` makes the options selectable, but it is still not handy. Try it in updated question.